# Computing weights of $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}_l(1)$ from the definition

Tags: etale-cohomology, weil-conjectures

This seems to be a trivial question, but I am genuinely confused about it.

The notion of weights as in [Deligne's Weil II](http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1980__52__137_0/) are defined in terms of eigenvalues of automorphisms that Frobenius morphisms induce on stalks. The following is a definition that is found in many literatures:

> Let $k$ be a finite field of $q = p^d$ elements, and $X_0$ be a scheme over $k$.
>   For an étale morphism $\phi:U_0 \to X_0$, it is a theorem that its pullback under the absolute Frobenius $Fr_{X_0}:X_0 \to X_0$ is isomorphic to $\phi$ itself. Via this isomorphism, for any sheaf $\mathcal{G}_0$ on (the étale site of) $X_0$ one can define a morphism $Fr_{X_0}^{\ast} \mathcal{G}_0 \to \mathcal{G}_0$, denoted by $Fr_{\mathcal{G}_0}$.
>
> Let $X$ be a pullback of $X_0$ via $k \to \bar{k}$, and $\mathcal{G}$ be a pullback of $\mathcal{G}_0$ via $X\to X_0$. Then pulling back $Fr_{\mathcal{G}_0}$ defines a morphism $F_X^{\ast}\mathcal{G} \to \mathcal{G}$, denoted by $F_{\mathcal{G}}$.
>
> For any geometric point $\bar{x}$ of $X$, whose underlying point $x$ has residue field of elements $q^d$, the $d$-th iteration of $F_X$ fixes $\bar{x}$, so pulling back the $d$-th iteration of $F_{\mathcal{G}}$ via $\bar{x}$ induces a morphism $\mathcal{G}_{\bar{x}}\to \mathcal{G}_{\bar{x}}$, which is called the geometric Frobenius.
>
> The weights of $\mathcal{G}$ at $\bar{x}$ are eigenvalues of this morphism.

Now in most of literatures, it is stated without proof that the weight of $\mathbb{Q}_l(1)$, the inverse limit of $\mu_{l^n}$s is $-2$. This looks intuitively clear: the arithmetic Frobenius, which can be proven to be inverse to the geometric Frobenius, **seems to be** acting on $\mu_{l^n}$ via $\xi \to \xi^{q^d}$, so its inverse has the weight $-2$.

However, I can't deduce this formally from the definition of the Frobenius map; it looks as if every maps in the sections of the Frobenius are canonical isomorphisms, so maps among stalks are the canonical isomorphisms as well. Can somebody formally deduce the computation of the weight of $\mathbb{Q}_l(1)$ from definitions?

Comment: Why isn't $\zeta \to \zeta^{q^d}$ a canonical isomorphism? Looks pretty canonical to me.

Comment: I am looking for a formal proof, whether that looks canonical to someone's eye or not is not relevant here.

Comment: I know that's not a proof. I only wrote that because the last couple paragraphs of your question seemed to demonstrate skepticism that the result is true, instead of just lack of knowledge of a complete proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is no point in including $X$ in the definition. We're interested in the stalk at $x$. We can also view $x$ as a geometric point of $X_0$. Pulling back from $X_0$ to $X$ and then taking the stalk is the same as taking the stalk at $x$, almost by definition.

By definition, the stalk of $\mathcal G_0$ at $x$ is the limit over all etale neighborhoods $U$ of $x$ of $\mathcal G_0(U)$. Recall that these are pairs of maps maps $a: \operatorname{Spec} \kappa \to U, b: U  \to X$ such that $b \circ a=i$ for a fixed map $i: \operatorname{Spec} \kappa \to X$.

On the other hand, the stalk of $Fr^* \mathcal G_0$ at $x$ is the limit over all etale neighborhoods $U'$ of $Fr(x)$ of $\mathcal G_0(U')$. In other word this is a limit over pairs of maps $a': \operatorname{Spec} \kappa \to U', b':U'  \to X$ such that $b'\circ a'= Fr_X \circ i$.

The natural isomorphism is noting that given data $U,b,a$ we have data $U', b',a'$ by taking $U'=U, b'=b$, $a' = Fr_U \circ a = a \circ Fr_{\kappa}$ because $b \circ Fr_U = Fr_X \circ b$. And we can reverse this by noting that $Fr_X$ has an inverse.

Now if $x$ happens to be stable under $Fr_X$, we get another isomorphism between these two where we simply take $(U',b',a')=(U,b,a)$.

Now if $\mathcal G_0$ happens to be $\mu_{\ell^n}$, the stalk of $\mathcal G_0$ at $x$ is naturally isomorphic to $\mu_{\ell^n}(\kappa)$. The isomorphism sends $s \in \mu_{\ell^n}(U)$ to $a^* s \in \mu_{\ell^n}(\kappa)$. This isomorphism is compatible with the second isomorphism $Fr^* \mathcal G_{0,x} \cong \mathcal G_{0,x}$, because that isomorphism sends $a^*s $ to $a^*s$.

But using this natural isomorphism to calculate the first isomorphism, it sends $a^* s \to Fr_{\kappa}^* a^* s$. In other words, Frobenius acts on the stalk $\mu_{\ell^n}(\kappa)$ by sending $\zeta \in \mu_{\ell^n}(\kappa)$ to $Fr^* \zeta = \zeta^q$.

The same thing works for $q^d$.

---

Why is the natural isomorphism what I said?

It's helpful to remember that $Fr^* \mathcal G ( U)$ is a limit over commutative squares

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    X @>Fr_X>> X\\
    @A{b}AA @AA{b'}A\\
    U @>>j> V
\end{CD}

where we then sheafify, and in this case the limit collapses to simply $V =U, b'=b, j = Fr_U$, and the sheafification is unnecessary. This shows that $Fr^* \mathcal G(U) =\mathcal G(U)$, and is the unique isomorphism in this level of generality.

If we then take a stalk at $x$, we'll take the limit of $\mathcal G(U)$ over triples $U, a,b$ as mentioned earlier. When we take the stalk of the pullback $(Fr_X^*\mathcal G)_x$, we get a limit over diagrams like this:

\begin{CD}
    X @>Fr_X>> X\\
    @A{b}AA @AA{b'}A\\
    U @>>j> V\\
@A{a}AA\\
\operatorname{Spec} \kappa
\end{CD}
and the natural isomorphism with $(\mathcal G)_{Fr(x)}$ is by viewing it as a limit over diagrams like

\begin{CD}
     @. X\\
    @. @AA{b'}A\\
    U @>>j> V\\
@A{a}AA\\
\operatorname{Spec} \kappa
\end{CD}

where $V$ plays the role $U$ did before and $j \circ a$ plays the role $a$ did before.

Our canonical isomorphism between these two things involves the identification $V= U, b'=b, j = Fr_U,$ and thus $j \circ a = Fr_U \circ a$. So that justifies what I said earlier.

Comment: I appreciate your writeup, but there are several issues:

Comment: First, you identify the map $i^*Fr_X^*\mathcal{G}_0\to i^*\mathcal{G}$ with a certain map between two direct limit (in the paragraph starting with "The natural isomorphism"). This looks plausible, but it wasn't deduced from the definition of the Frobenius map $F_{\mathcal{G}_0}$, stated in the original question. This is the part that I am confused the most: wiring up some morphism that looks canonical to the definition of the Frobenius morphism.

Comment: @user545 The trick here is that if you work with a general sheaf $\mathcal G$ and you don't assume $x$ is stable under $Fr_x$ then there is only one canonical isomorphism. So you want to stay in that setting for as long as possible, to avoid errors.

Comment: Next, it seems that your argument proves that the geometric Frobenius induces an automorphism on the stalk with eigenvalue $q$, which implies that $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}_l(1)$ is pure of weight $2$, not $-2$ as assumed in many literatures. This means your argument is wrong at some point, which I suspect is the part that interprets $i^*Fr_X^*\mathcal{G}_0 \to i^*\mathcal{G}_0$ as a morphism between direct limits.

Comment: @user545 The factor of $q$ is reversed because I wrote the map $\mathcal G_0 \to Fr^* \mathcal G_0$ and not the other way around.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, so the map between direct limits you've described is actually the map $i^*\mathcal{G}_0 \to i^*Fr_X^* \mathcal{G}_0$. However, _why_ is that is the part that I'm confused the most.

Comment: @user545 I will write something to explain this later...

Comment: Now I feel like I understand why I was confused: I thought somehow that the arithmetic Frobenius is something like geometric Frobenius on $Spec \bar{k}$, but in fact it wasn't. $\mathcal{G}_0$ was pulled back from $X_0$, so this is already asymmetric between $X_0$ and $Spec \bar{k}$.. Your writeup now makes sense to me when every instance of $Fr_X, Fr_U$ are removed and only $Fr_{\bar{k}}$ is left, so that it was about arithmetic Frobenius  from the beginning. Somehow geometric Frobenius is an alien object because of étale covering of $X$ that is not a lift from $X_0$..

Comment: @user545 Does this help at all?

Comment: Yes, thank you!